# Controling the Voltage of alternator

Tags: voltage, mosfet

I want to design a circuit to control the output voltage generated by car alternator in a way that it shouldn't allow voltage to exceed 15V and also when the output voltage of alternator is less than 10 V, it must have the output voltage around 0 V. Actually it should approximately be able to convert The output Voltage of alternator between 10-14.7V to output voltage of 0-14V. The maximum output current of this device doesn't exceed 8A. I designed a circuit with MJ11016 and it worked well, but the problem is the size of this transistor, it makes my board very large (I used the similar circuit three times in my board). Can I use MOSFET instead of MJ11016 to control the voltage?[image]

I designed another circuit as below, but the problem is that the drop voltage is 1.5V? How can I boost the voltage?
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, your circuit maybe doesn't do what you might think you want. With an input voltage of (say) 10.1 volts, the output voltage (under load) will be about 9.4 volts. However, if this is acceptable then you could use a buck regulator with under-voltage lock-out (UVLO). At voltages slightly about 10V (as per your design) the output voltage will be slightly below 10V and as the input voltage rises to about 11 volts, the output will rise but lag below the input by maybe 0.5 volts.

Alternatively you could use a buck-boost regulator that would attempt to produce 14V from inputs as low as a few volts to well over 20V. Again if the 10V lock-out is important, most of the chips available come with UVLO pins or you can use a disable pin driven from a comparator that senses the input supply voltage.

Here's one that Linear tech's parametric search engine (8A, 14V o/p with input between 8V and 22V) found: -

[image]

It will be capable of 8A output but with different output transistors. Power efficiency will be around the 95% mark. The RUN pin can force the device into shut-down and serves as an UVLO pin with a potential divider from the incoming power rail. Read the data sheet for details.

Comment: I read the datasheet but couldn't understand exactly what will happen in boost situation! I want to use the similar circuit to apply boost situation for my edited circuit in my main question? Do have any idea?